# Unable to boot Ubuntu after password protect Grub Boot Loader

Tags: boot, grub2

Everything is set up according to the instructions from https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-password-protect-the-grub-boot-loader-in-ubuntu/.
When I reboot the system I get an error saying`System BootOrder not found. Initializing defaults.`
I tried 1. BootRepair
2. tried to reinstall grub by `sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` 
3. tried to reinstall grub in the efi format partition.
///update///
Solved, problem occur because mine is dual-boot. Thanks for the phenomenal help.

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: And the RP explicitly says to practice first: *"Although this process isn't terribly difficult, I do recommend practicing the steps on a virtual machine first. You don't want to just dive into this on a production machine, only to find you've locked yourself out, and the system won't boot."*